# How do I cut and paste effectively between applications while using EXWM?

Tags: copy-paste, exwm

For example, I am trying to copy the URL line from Firefox into an org mode buffer. The usual cut and paste keys for Firefox (C-c C-v) do not work, and neither does (M-w C-y).

To copy from Firefox (in this example), I have to use the right mouse button context menu and select "Copy" which is suboptimal to say the least.

I've googled and gone through the documentation but can't seem to find any reference to the kill buffer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Long answer**:

There are three modes* in `EXWM`.

**I**. Sending all the keys to the apps except the global bindings (for e.g. this is a global `(exwm-input-set-key (kbd "s-c") #'list-processes)`. `EXWM` calls this `char-mode`

**II**. Sending all the keys to the apps with some simulations. `EXWM` calls this `line-mode`. You can define simulations like.

```lisp
(exwm-input-set-simulation-keys
 '(([?\C-b] . left)
  ([?\C-f] . right)))
```

Now in this mode if I press `C-f` apps receive `right` arrow key.

**III**. Not sending any key to the apps, instead Emacs receives all the keys. So you can use normal operations like `C-x 2` or `C-x 3` to split the window.`EXWM` calls this `line-mode` too.

`C-c` and `C-v` doesn't work because you're in mode **III**. Here are some of the helper functions that I use.

```lisp
(defun fhd/exwm-input-line-mode ()
  "Set exwm window to line-mode and show mode line"
  (call-interactively #'exwm-input-grab-keyboard)
  (exwm-layout-show-mode-line))

(defun fhd/exwm-input-char-mode ()
  "Set exwm window to char-mode and hide mode line"
  (call-interactively #'exwm-input-release-keyboard)
  (exwm-layout-hide-mode-line))

(defun fhd/exwm-input-toggle-mode ()
  "Toggle between line- and char-mode"
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer (window-buffer)
    (when (eq major-mode 'exwm-mode)
      (if (equal (second (second mode-line-process)) "line")
          (fhd/exwm-input-char-mode)
        (fhd/exwm-input-line-mode)))))
```

To make it globally available with `s-i`

```
(exwm-input-set-key (kbd "s-i") #'fhd/exwm-input-toggle-mode)
```

This toggles between modes **I** and either mode **II** or **III**.
Switching between mode **II** and mode **III** depends on `exwm-input-line-mode-passthrough`. Another helper function I use:

```lisp
(defun fhd/toggle-exwm-input-line-mode-passthrough ()
  (interactive)
  (if exwm-input-line-mode-passthrough
    (progn
      (setq exwm-input-line-mode-passthrough nil)
      (message "App receives all the keys now (with some simulation)"))
   (progn
     (setq exwm-input-line-mode-passthrough t)
     (message "emacs receives all the keys now")))
  (force-mode-line-update))
```

And to bind it globally

```
(exwm-input-set-key (kbd "s-p") 'fhd/toggle-exwm-input-line-mode-passthrough)
```

I used `(force-mode-line-update)` in this function since I have an indicator in my mode-line to show if emacs receives all the keys (mode **III**) or apps receive all the keys with some simulations (mode **II**) if mode-line is hidden it means we are in mode **I** and apps receive all the keys without any simulations. To make sure apps open in mode **II** you can use `(setq exwm-input-line-mode-passthrough nil)`.

If you want all the apps to open in mode **I** (that is `char-mode` in `EXWM` terminology) you can use:

```lisp
(add-hook 'exwm-manage-finish-hook
  (lambda () (call-interactively #'exwm-input-release-keyboard)
     (exwm-layout-hide-mode-line)))
```

*The word "mode" is used loosely, it doesn't mean in `EXWM` there are actually three modes.

**Short answer**

Call `exwm-input-release-keyboard` function. It switches to `char-mode` which means firefox receives all the key events.

Comment: Thanks fhdsni, that's just what I'm after. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading the [guide](https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/wiki) and seems it's also possible to prefix all the usual shortcuts with `C-c C-q` (`exwm-input-send-next-key`) without switching to `char-mode`. So instead of `C-a`/`C-c`/`C-v` use `C-c-q-a`/`C-c-q-c`/`C-c-q-v`.

Answer (score 0):

If the above approach don't work for you(mine did not), try it this way. First, we set to open all application in `char-mode` by default.

```
;; The code from user - fhdhsni
(add-hook 'exwm-manage-finish-hook
  (lambda () (call-interactively #'exwm-input-release-keyboard)
  (exwm-layout-hide-mode-line)))
```

Then if you want to go back to `line-mode`, just do `exwm-reset`. The default keybinding is - `s-r`